# How not to overwrite Same columns name when multiple tables are joined SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have an sql statement that retrives information from multiple tables but some of them have same columns name.

For exemple the **products** table has the *image* column which can also be found in the **manufacturer** table.
I don't want to overwrite the product image with the manufacturer image. I only need to get the *name* column from the **manufacturer** table AS "manufacturer" . The rest needs to r

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you just need that one column, `SELECT m.name AS mfr_name, p.*, pd.* FROM ...` else list all the columns you need and add `AS` alias names where appropriate.

Comment: Alternatively you may use positional column values accessing, not by their name. But this is NOT recommended solution.

Comment: SELECT individually and put alias on each column EG: SELECT manu.id m_id, manu.column2 m_column2, prod.id prod_id, prod.manu_id prod_m_id FROM manufacturer manu LEFT OUTER JOIN products  prod  ON prod_m_id = manu.id